# How to create Seed Scenarios in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel provides a feature that allows you to create generic data required to bring an application up on first run. Often the seeds consist of things like a list of countries, ingredients, user roles, and maybe even a default user.

When writing tests, you can also use Faker et al for creating temporary datasets.

Both of these features are great and exceptionally fit to purpose.

Sometimes, however, we have a need to run manual tests of Laravel web applications that consist of dozens of tables and hundreds or thousands of rows of data (or even hundreds of thousands of rows). For example, if we want to load test a web application, we need to generate all of this data (rather than using actual production data).

I would like to modify the artisan `migrate --seed` command to include `--scenario=loadtesting` to tell Laravel which seed files to use or to be able to set a flag inside the seed files that says `if ( 'loadtesting' == $scenario ) { $rows = 1000000; }`.

I looked at the Seeder.php class inside the Illuminate folder (well, a subfolder of Illuminate) but I don't see any opportunity to interrupt the flow of the seed creation process.

I'm wondering if someone can detail the steps required to implement the above feature without overwriting the Laravel files (anything in vendor, to be precise). I suspect [Faker's ORM features](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#populating-entities-using-an-orm-or-an-odm) could play a key role in whatever solution is recommended.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you how I do it sometimes.
A flag in `.env` and `config` for setting which seeder classes to call.

```
APP_DB_TESTING = 'scenario1';
```

Then in seeder

```php
public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RolePermissionTableSeeder::class);

        if (config('app.scenario') === 'scenario1')
        {
            $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(TagsTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
        }

    }
```

or you can create custom `artisan` commands that fire different seeders. For example, create a custom command called `LoadArticles` and add:

```php
public function handle()
{
    DB::table('articles')->truncate();
    $this->call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'ArticlesTableSeeder']);
}
```

which then you can call for different testing situations

Comment: This is perfect. Where would we add the `handle()` function?

Comment: @TedStresen-Reuter `handle` is a [laravel command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#writing-commands) method

Comment: In a custom artisan command. ```php artisan make:command CustomTableSeeder```. That way you can use/call it as any other artisan command